# Aginity SQL error message shows wrong character

Tags: aginity

When I make a query in Aginity with an error in it, it gives a notification like

```
ERROR:  '[My SQL here]'
error
^ found "INSERT" (at char 2292) expecting `SELECT' or `'(''
```

If I click on the location of that error in my SQL, it's actually at Position: 3934.  I think Aginity is disregarding the whitespace when it tries to say where the error is.  Is there a way to make it show the position in the builder?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Aginity that does this, it's somewhere up the software stack (I suspect it's on the actual Netezza itself).

What I do (and this is a POOR solution) is to remove the whitespace myself.

Since I use Unix (mostly) and Vim this is a little easier than in Aginity.

It really is a PITA, and IBM should proved a better solution (one would be to kick back the SQL statement *as run* with all the whitespace removed).